# How do I run r function as R script?

Tags: r

I have a function called `function_test` saved as `testcode.r` file. 
I have been running it like this (with all the required parameters within R environment):

```
function_test(p1, p2 , p3 , p4)
```

What do I need to do to Run it like this in linux terminal?

```
Rscript testcode.r \

–p1 param1 \

–p2 param2  \

–p3 param3 \

--p4 param4
```

Comment: maybe `R.exe -e "source('testcode.r'); function_test(param1, param2 , param3 , param4)"`? but not sure how you are going to use the output from the function in command line

Comment: This doesn't work. Do you do this in R? or in linux terminal? Does the output of this work in both windows and linux environment? I need this so I could  run this script in cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add this as the first line to your function file, before the function definition starts:

```
args=commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
```

Depending on the number of arguments required by your function:

```
function_test(param1=args[2],param2=args[3],param3=args[4],param4=args[5])
```

The `args` vector stores everything you pass from command line as a character, so you might have to do type conversion if your function is expecting objects as a `numeric` for example.

Then call your script from command line like this:

```
Rscript testcode.r --args arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this method, but is it possible to have labels tagged (`-p1 param1`), for each param entered? Exactly the way I want to submit the job?

Comment: The order in which you give the parameters will be the order in which they are stored in the vector. So if you always give arguments in the order p1,p2,p3,p4 you can assign the values of args as intended to the param fields. I don't think you can tag arguments from command line.

Comment: You can tag arguments. I need to do this for publication of this code (something what reviewers are asking for).

Comment: @MAPK I don't know to do that. If you know it please suggest an edit. I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: Found it here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/parse-arguments-of-an-r-script/

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/argparse/vignettes/argparse.html