# How do you pass argument in R function to run in cluster/linux environment?

Tags: r, arguments

I am trying to run a function in cluster. This function is saved as `testcode.r`. I run this code first and I have been doing something like this to run the function:

`function_test(p1, p2 , p3 , p4)`

How can I parse these arguments for commandline submission of this code in linux environment? I want to be able to submit the job like this:

```
Rscript testcode.r \

–p1 parameter1 \

–p2 parameter2  \

–p3 parameter3 \

--p4 parameter4
```

Comment: This link might help you: https://www.r-bloggers.com/parse-arguments-of-an-r-script/

Comment: identical qn: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920960/how-do-i-run-r-function-as-r-script